# Why is isoclinic rotation preferred in spaces of $d \gt 3$ dimensions?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, spacetime-dimensions

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221881/), for example, takes it for granted that double rotations of objects in four-space will naturally tend to decay into isoclinic rotations.

But, why? How does that transfer occur? It seems to me that angular momentum should be independently conserved in each available rotational plane, so transfer between planes should be impossible for a body in isolation. If that is not the case, how can we define a conserved angular momentum in higher-dimensional spaces? And does this momentum transfer depend on physical characteristics of the object? E.g., would a perfectly rigid object be able to maintain non-isoclinic rotation longer than a deformable object (or indefinitely)?

Comment: I hope this helps you, There is an answer:
[Bend Dimensions Spatial to Algebraic (Tensor problem)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/707047/)

Answer (score 0):

The Clifford Algebra for this might be that the bivector for double rotation ae12+be34 may be written as a sum of two commuting and orthogonal isoclinic rotations [(a+b)(e12+e34)+(a-b)(e12-e34)]/2.

Comment: That doesn't really seem to resolve the fundamental issue; if you factor into left and right isoclinic rotations, it still looks to me like there are two orthogonal components of angular momentum that must be conserved; how do you end up with one of them being suppressed and all the energy transferred into the other?